# How to avoid replacement of new lines with \n in Ansible file lookup?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I am trying to fetch the content of `foo.txt` as it is however when I am doing a `lookup` the new lines are getting replaced with `\n`.

How to avoid this and get the content of file as it is?

**`foo.txt`**:

```
This is dummy1
This is dummy2
This is dummy3
This is dummy4
This is dummy5
```

**Playbook:**

```yaml
- name: Gather info on backend servers
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.file', '/tmp/foo.txt') }}"
```

**Output:**

```json
TASK [ansible.builtin.debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "This is dummy1\nThis is dummy2\nThis is dummy3\nThis is dummy4\nThis is dummy5"
}
```

I want Ansible to print as below:

```yaml
TASK [ansible.builtin.debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "This is dummy1
    This is dummy2
    This is dummy3
    This is dummy4
    This is dummy5"

}
```

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge, that is currently not possible, though there are some suggestions on how to work around this in [this thread on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/640130/display-output-with-ansible).

The imho easiest solution would be this:

```yaml
    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.file', '/tmp/foo.txt').split('\n') }}"
```

Comment: The mentioned thread [contains also the correct solution](https://serverfault.com/a/683275/448950) to address the initial problem.

Comment: Thanks @toydarian... this is close to what i want to achieve.
TASK [ansible.builtin.debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "This is dummy1",
        "This is dummy2",
        "This is dummy3",
        "This is dummy4",
        "This is dummy5"
    ]
}
I don't want the quotes as well.

Comment: The output is JSON formatted, as mentioned in the other answer. If you don't want that, you need to use a different callback plugin, as suggested there.